# PyCharm inserting tab characters even though I have specified to use only spaces

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm on Windows, below is the version information:

```
PyCharm 2019.1 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.5849.23, built on February 27, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+159 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

When I am editing code and hit enter it sometimes inserts a tab character when I expect it to insert only spaces, as I have configured the editor to always use 4 spaces per indentation level.  For example, if I have a long line that I want the editor to split nicely for me I may hit enter between two parameters in a function signature, with the expectation that the indentation provided by the editor will use spaces only rather than tab characters, but I get tabs instead of 4 spaces.

So the following code is split correctly, but instead of spaces in the second line before the second parameter I have tab characters:

```
example_function(arg1,
                 arg2)
```

I have unchecked "Use tab character" in Settings->Editor->Code Style->Python->Tabs and Indents, so this seems to be affected by another setting.

When can I manage this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

LOL - I have the exact opposite problem. I want to use TAB characters, I have 'Use tab character' checked and it refuses to insert TAB characters, only spaces. Something is seriously wrong with PyCharm's handling of indentation. Using version 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)